# Is there any reason to merge a feature branch into a forked master before making a pull request?

Tags: git, github

I work on open source code on GitHub. The only workflow I've followed is:

1. For a project that I want to fix a bug or add a feature to, I fork the repository
2. I clone my forked repository locally
3. I create a branch for the feature or bug fix
4. I do the work and make commits in the new branch
5. I push my local branch with the new commits to my remote fork
6. Finally, I click create pull request on GitHub, and I request to merge my feature/bug fix branch into the upstream master branch

This has worked without issue. However, I've wondered, would there be any reason why I would want to merge my fork's feature or bug fix branch into my fork's master branch **and then** do a pull request from my master to the upstream master? Would there be any other reason to merge my feature or bug fix branch into my fork's master in this type of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

Generally, there is no reason to merge your feature branch into your master branch. That is the task of the upstream.

### Longer story

I can imagine cases, where it would make sense to do the merge. For example, you may have reason to fork your feature branch off from an early commit (you would do that if you fix a bug; then you may want to make the fix available for earlier releases). But then it may occur that merging the fix into the a modern master branch becomes non-trivial. For example, complicated merge conflicts could arise. Then you want to warn the integrator that the resolution of the conflicts has to look like "this branch in my fork". But you would not make a pull request with the merge result, unless the upstream asks for it.